# About proceessing a csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

The real dataset is a. csv file. But first four rows is not in csv format except all rows are in csv [I have added the screen shot of the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aNjz.jpg)format.

How to read that csv file using pd. read_csv without the first 4 rows.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html - the best way is to go through the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this skiprow option from pandas

```
pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, skiprows=4)
```